# JsonSerializationException When Creating JToken from Mock Object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, json.net, moq

I have a following line of code that I am trying to get past in unit testing with mocking up a certain class that makes calls internally to databases (not by my design):

```
var configuration = config.SelectToken("config").ToObject<Configuration>();
```

I am trying to mock up the Configuration class and add it, as well as the "config" property name, to an instance of JObject:

```
var mockConfig= new Mock<Configuration>();

var jToken = JToken.FromObject(mockConfig);

dynamic jsonObject = new JObject
{
    {"config", jToken }
};
```

While trying to create a JToken from the mock object, I am receiving the following exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : A member with the name 'Mock' already exists on 'Castle.Proxies.ConfigurationProxy'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.

Comment: What is that configuration class? Is that from System.Configuration?  And what are you trying to do with this mock? It would help to see what kind of actions you are calling and asserting on the mock.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when I try to serialize a mock object with Newtonsoft Json.